# "I doubt" vs. "I suspect"

Tags: difference, phrase-request

When I am doubtful about something I may say

> I doubt it is true

Before, I used "suspect" interchangeably

> I suspect it is true

But as I checked "suspect" means that I think *it is rather true*?!

In general, except *doubt* and *suspect* which words can be used in the same meaning for such purpose (to express one doubts)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you `doubt` something is true, you think something isn't true/right or you think it is highly unlikely to be true.

Whereas when you are `suspecting` something to be true, you have a feeling that this thing actually is true.

If you want to express you aren't sure about something but you think it's true, you can use `guess`, `reckon` or `suppose`.

As for synonyms for "doubt": I would probably use `might`...e.g. "It might be true." (but I don't think it's likely).

Comment: Thank you, what about the synonyms for "doubt", what if I think it is unlikely?

Comment: Thank you, I just needed check dictionary for *suspect* we can also say *"have a suspicion, have a feeling, feel, be inclined to think, fancy, reckon, guess, surmise, conjecture, think, think it probable/likely, have a sneaking feeling, have a hunch; be of the opinion, suppose, conclude, expect, presume, consider, deduce, infer, glean, sense, imagine;
be afraid, fear, have a foreboding;
formalopine
"I began to suspect that she had made a mistake"*

Comment: For *doubt* synonyms are *think something unlikely, have (one's) doubts about, question, query, be dubious, lack conviction, have reservations about
"I doubt whether he will come"*

Comment: By the way, in the 18th and early 19th century, *I doubt* had pretty much the opposite meaning that it has today.  *I doubt it will be troublesome* had the approximate meaning of *I fear it will be troublesome* in the current sense.

Comment: If you _doubt_ that it's true, you _suspect_ that it is NOT true.

Comment: @Brian Hitchcock Yes....so? It should be clear from the explanations that they have opposite meanings...(`doubt`:"..you think something **isn't  true**..", `suspect`: "you have a feeling that it **is true**").

Answer (score 1):

*From vocabulary.com.*

**[Suspect](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/suspect)**

To suspect someone of something is to believe that they probably did it.

- hold in suspicion; believe to be guilty/imagine to be the case or true or probable
- someone who is under suspicion (noun)
- not as expected (adj)

[doubt](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/suspect)

When you're in doubt, you really can't tell what's true and what's false.

- consider unlikely or have doubts about
- the state of being unsure of something (noun)

(*Both the words can be used as a verb and a noun*, however, *suspect can also be used as an adjective*)